# React - Redirect with navigate(), send props to page

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a few cards on my page that all lead to the same page like this:

```js
{
  notes.map((card) => (
    <div key={card.id} onClick={() => navigate("/EditNotes", { card })}>
      <NoteCard title={card.NoteTitle} bgColor={card.CardColor} />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

In `navigate('/EditNotes', {card})` section how can I send the value of `card` to the `/EditNotes`  page as this doesn't seem to work.

In the `EditNotes` Page I do this:

```js
const EditNotes = ({ card }) => {
  console.log(card);
  //...
}
```

However the `console.log` shows `undefiend` 
Does anyone know how to pass props using the `navigate()` thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `navigate` to `/EditNotes/${card?.id}` then you can get the note by its **id**.

```
{
  notes.map((card)=>(
      <div key={card.id} onClick={()=> navigate(`/EditNotes/${card?.id}`)}>
          <NoteCard title={card.NoteTitle} bgColor={card.CardColor} />
      </div>
  ))
}
```

Then in you **router**:

```
<Route path="/EditNotes/:id" element={<EditNote />} />
```

Then in your **EditNotes** component:

```
const EditNotes = ()=>{
   const { id } = useParams(); //get the id passed in the route
   //get the note by its id
   //...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try to pass the 'card' prop to the 'EditNotes' component as an object with the state key as the second argument in the navigate():

```
{
  notes.map((card)=>(
    <div key={card.id} onClick={()=> navigate('/EditNotes', { state: { card } })}>
      <NoteCard title={card.NoteTitle} bgColor={card.CardColor} />
    </div>
  ))
}

const EditNotes = ({ location }) => {
  const { card } = location.state;
  console.log(card);
  // rest of the code...
};
```

You can then access the card object from the location.state object in the 'EditNotes' component if that makes sense.

Comment: thanks - i am getting an errror of: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state'). I am not importing something or?

Comment: The location object (location.state) is undefined in the component where you are trying to access it (EditNotes). To make EditNotes have access to the location prop you need to ensure that it is being rendered as a child component of a <Route> component in your app.